# Change of Variable formula yielding different answer.

Tags: probability, transformation

The question says $X = \frac{1}{2}(1+x)$ for $-1<x<1$. Its asking us to find the PDF of the random variable $Y = X^2$.

When I apply change of variable rule, I get $(\frac{1}{4 \sqrt y }+\frac{1}{2})$ and when I apply the CDF rule I get something else. My textbook says the answer is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt y }$. Can someone explain??

Comment: Your answer is correct. $X^{2}$ has values in $(0,1)$ and the given answer is not even a PDF in that interval.

Comment: Go to 'How to find the probability, mean and cdf using a pdf - Mathematics .'..in this site

Answer (score 1):

The textbook is correct. I think you meant to say that the pdf for $X$ is given by $f(x)={1\over2}(1+x)$. Consider $y=x^2$. For a given $y$ there are two solutions, $x_+=\sqrt{y}$ and $x_-=-\sqrt{y}$.
As usual,
$$g(y) = f(x_+)\left\vert{\partial y\over\partial x}\vert_{x=x_+} \right\vert^{-1}+f(x_-)\left\vert{\partial y\over\partial x}\vert_{x=x_-} \right\vert^{-1}$$
So,
$$g(y)={1\over2}\left(1+\sqrt{y}\right){1\over2\sqrt{y}}+{1\over2}\left(1-\sqrt{y}\right){1\over2\sqrt{y}}={1\over2\sqrt{y}}$$

Comment: Did you mean to write $\partial x/\partial y$? Because $\partial y/\partial x = 2x = \pm 2\sqrt{y}$

Comment: It is correct as written - note exponent (-1).

Comment: Hmm, how did I miss that...